# Why does fopen() function throws error when char is passed into it?

Tags: c, fopen

I'm using the `fopen` function (can be found here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fopen.htm) to read from a text file in C. The function prototype definition is:

`FILE *fopen( const char * filename, const char * mode );`

Seeing that the second parameter (`mode`) requires that I pass in a `char`, I wrote the following:

`fp = fopen("testfile", 'w');`

However, this threw a segmentation fault. When I replaced it with:

`fp = fopen("testfile", "w");`

the error disappeared. Why is it that a `string` was required as the second parameter, and not the `char`as the prototype indicated?

Comment: 'w' is a char, "w" is a char* -- fopen() wants a char*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look again at the function declaration.  The `mode` parameter is of type `const char *`, i.e. a pointer to a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

The mode parameter is a pointer. When you pass a char it interprets that as a pointer so the code tries to read some random memory. Luckily, the random memory is not readable so the code seg faults.